# Python multiprocessing is running all my code 5 times

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, discord.py, pool

I have made a discord bot which uses multiprocessing (it is my first time using multiprocessing) in order to improve efficiency.  The bot already works fine without it, i was just bored and wanted to improve it.  This bot is for a school's discord server which just gets the lunch for the day using their api (idek why they have one).

For some reason my multiprocessing is forcing my code to run 5 times, and somehow is causing my discord bot to send 5x the messages than it should.  I honestly have no idea what's happening with this. I run the function before anything to do with my bot and somehow it makes 5 bots run concurrently with the same token.  It takes about 30s for all 5 bots to come online, which they do one by one. One more minor thing is that the multiprocessing prints "none" 5 times for no reason every time the func is called.

Thanks you for taking your time to ready my thread!

```
from asyncio.tasks import create_task
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import datetime, asyncio
from discord.message import Message
import schedule
import random
import requests
import json
import datetime
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool



def get_lunch(day):  # Sorting thru a json that is scraped, not gonna put it here b/c i don't want to dox myself, and it works perfectly
    all_todos = load_pre_reqs()
    gotten_lunch = (str(all_todos.split("menu_items")[2 + day].split(r'"name"')[1].split(",")[0]))
    formated_lunch = (gotten_lunch[3:int(len(gotten_lunch)) -1 ])
    return(formated_lunch)

# if anyone is trying to run this code u can use something like instead of above
# def get_lunch(day):
#     lunches = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
#     return lunches[day]
def lunch():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = Pool(5)
        week = p.map(get_lunch, range(5))
        return week

# I run this^ on it's own and works well, but causes the rest of the code to repeat 5x

print(lunch())

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')
client = discord.Client()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # here for future
TOKEN = 'insert token here'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"connected as {client.user}")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    else:
        await message.channel.send("hi") #just here to make sure bot is running


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation in the `multiprocessing` module is quite clear about that.  When you run a module with multiprocessing, that launches a brand new process, with a brand new interpreter, which has to import your main module and all the modules it needs.  If you don't have your one-time-only code in an `if __name__=='__main__':` block, like the documentation suggests, then it will get re-run in every process that launches.

This is why you should get in the habit of putting your app's main code in an `def main():` and doing

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The multiprocessing-launched imports will not have `__name__` set that way.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But I don't exactly understand.  Are you saying I should put all of my code in main()?  Or am I putting just some, and if so what code, and how would I call the functions now that they are nested?

Comment: Any code that should only be executed ONCE should be in main.  The secondary processes will not run `main`.